# Galaxy A50 won't boot up or even try to

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot, screen, power-on

I was on my phone looking at twitter and then it just suddenly stopped working, i thought it was some app crash but my whole phone wasn't working, not even the power button.

I force restarted my phone and restarted it, the boot screen showed up and then disappeared.

I tried charging it but it doesn't show anything, i tried to remove the sim card, i tried to boot into recovery mode and my attempts were unsuccessful, and the screen is not the problem as my phone doesn't even vibrate after booting up.

Somehow, i got my phone working again for a couple minutes, i pressed the power button and the battery showed up (i had 45%) and the boot screen showed up, but the was stuck on that screen this time, i force quitted my phone and next thing you know my phone is still broken.

My phone has a lot of space left (50GB), it isn't very old, (i've had it for like 10 months) and the charging port is working well, i tried it on my switch and it does the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it by any chance physical problem like water damage (wet air or pocket) or dropped on the floor? is behavior same with keeping charger connected over night? might it be the case that it's still **on** but unresponsive?

Comment: No, i was staying on my phone and it just flat out froze, i was in my bed, it isn't a screen problem as i said because it turned on again for a minute but was stuck on the boot screen nor is it on because i tried to make it ring using another phone, and finally i kept it charging for over 2 hours now i'm pretty sure it's battery is full.

Comment: press Power for 30 seconds to see if there is some kind of response. or watch youtube how to disassemble in order to disconnect battery

Comment: I've looked further into the problem and it seems to be a software issue, the power button doesn't do anything, it's practically unusuable and removing the battery would be useless because the phone is already off and i could risk damaging the phone. I will go check tomorrow and go to samsung to fix it.